# SQL Server 2012 linked server error 7303

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc, dsn

odbc 32 bits is created on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bits (Windows\SysWoW64). The test of the connection of the odbc 32 bits is working well. but linked server in SQL Server 2012 64 bits gives this error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "databaseX". OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "databaseX" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

It's also working well on Windows 7 64 bit driver in combination with Excel. Can you help?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I Have a same problem. Verify:

Driver ODBC is the same version (32 or 64 bit) of driver MySQL.

On ODBC related (32 or 64 bit version) create, configure and test the connection;
Look on the ODBC(32) System DSN appears the configuration created on the ODBC(64) System DSN.
I´m sorry for not publish a print screen. Why i´m a new user.

And then create a linked server for a ODBC.